# How do i fixed error in my function with codeigniter 3 and jquery 1.12.4

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter-3

I created a tabs function using jquery-1.12.4, the tab was successfully executed but there was always an error in $ (...). datepickers is not a function, sometimes also $ (...). tabs is not a function. I am really confused, the mistake always leads to one of these functions. How to fixed?

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('select[name="farea_id"]').change(function(){
    var url = window.location.href;    
    url = url.substring(0, (url.indexOf("index.php") == -1) ? url.length : url.indexOf("index.php"));
    var sendto = url+"index.php/ajax/get_i_fprovince/" + jQuery(this).val();
    $("#i_fprovince").load(encodeURI(sendto));
}); 

$('#i_fprovince').change(function(){
    var url = window.location.href;    
    url = url.substring(0, (url.indexOf("index.php") == -1) ? url.length : url.indexOf("index.php"));
    var sendto = url+"index.php/ajax/get_i_fcity_id/" + jQuery('select[name="fprovince_id"]').val();
    $("#i_fcity").load(encodeURI(sendto));
});

$('select[name="region"]').change(function(){
    var url = window.location.href;    
    url = url.substring(0, (url.indexOf("index.php") == -1) ? url.length : url.indexOf("index.php"));
    var sendto = url+"index.php/ajax/get_region/" + jQuery(this).val();
    $("#i_region_parent").load(encodeURI(sendto));
}); 

$('select[name="cust_id"]').change(function(){ 
    var url = window.location.href;    
    url = url.substring(0, (url.indexOf("index.php") == -1) ? url.length : url.indexOf("index.php"));
    var sendto = url+"index.php/ajax/get_i_initial_cust/" + jQuery(this).val();
    $("#fproject_initial").load(encodeURI(sendto));
});

$('.delete').click(function(){
    var answer = confirm('Are you sure to delete "'+jQuery(this).attr('title')+'" ?');
    return answer; 
}); 

$( function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy" );
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "altFormat", "dd/mm/yy" );
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "showButtonPanel", true );
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "currentText", "Today" );
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "showOn", "both" );

    $( "#tasktab" ).tabs({
        beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
                ui.panel.html(
                    "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible." 
                );
            });
        }
    });

    $( "#oprtab" ).tabs({
        beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
                ui.panel.html(
                    "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible." 
                );
            });
        }
    });

} );

$(".addintab").click(function() {
    $("#tasktab_content").load(encodeURI(jQuery(this).attr('href'))); 
    return false;
});

$(".cancelintab").click(function() {
    var sendto = jQuery(this).attr('sendto');
    var subm = jQuery(this).attr('subm');
    $("#tasktab_content").load(encodeURI(sendto)); 
    return false;
});

$('.deleteintab').click(function(){
    var answer = confirm('Are you sure to delete "'+jQuery(this).attr('title')+'" ?');
    if(answer) $("#tasktab_content").load(encodeURI(jQuery(this).attr('href'))); 
    return false; 
});
```

});

Comment: Sounds like you do not have jquery included in your code. Make sure the JQuery library is referenced in your pages.

Comment: Can you paste the code where you have referenced jQuery and the datepicker files?

Comment: like this in my page : 
<link href="http://xxxxxx/xxxx/application/third_party/assets/css/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxxxxx/xxxx/application/third_party/assets/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxxxxx/xxxx/application/third_party/assets/js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: Have you tried using jquery cdn `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js` and see if the error still there?

Comment: It seems you have not included jQuery-UI

Comment: Hasta Dhana
yes i've tried it, and with the same error too

Comment: have you  using datepicker plugins?

Comment: i make datepicker with jquery ui

Comment: if i try to using cdn https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js my web are refresh  automatically in 5 seconds and cannot to access other